# Catch checked change event of a checkbox

Tags: jquery, unchecked

How do I to catch check/uncheck event of `<input type="checkbox" />` with jQuery?

Comment: If you are using a relatively new version of JQuery, i would use the .on('change', function(){...}) as mentioned in @Daniel De Leon's answer below. An advantage, the "on" event listener will bind to dynamically generated html.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="something" />

$("#something").click( function(){
   if( $(this).is(':checked') ) alert("checked");
});
```

Edit: Doing this will not catch when the checkbox changes for other reasons than a click, like using the keyboard. To avoid this problem, listen to `change`instead of `click`.

For checking/unchecking programmatically, take a look at [Why isn't my checkbox change event triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869981/why-isnt-my-checkbox-change-event-triggered)

Comment: document.getElementById('something').checked works,why $('#something').checked not work?

Comment: Your code is missing a paran, and really should use the jQuery way of getting the check state.

Comment: Because $('#something') returns a jQuery object not an ElementNode

Comment: Shore: the reason getElementById works is that it returns a DOM element, whereas the $ jQuery function returns a jQuery object. The jQuery object has the DOM element as a property, but it is not, itself, a DOM object.

Comment: this.checked should work... try making an alert(this) an check that you have the correct element.

Comment: I know I'm arriving late to the party, but this only works when a "click" event triggers this.   

If for some reason you were to do something like this elsewhere in the code: $("#something").attr("checked", "checked") the click event would never get triggered.

Comment: @DavidStinemetze: I'd say that you could listen ton `change` instead of click. I'm updating the answer

Comment: I also think `change` is better than `clicked`.

Comment: Why add a note about using change event but not change the demo code?.

Answer (score 45):

The click will affect a label if we have one attached to the input checkbox?

I think that is better to use the .change() function

```
<input type="checkbox" id="something" />

$("#something").change( function(){
  alert("state changed");
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as the question is about listening for a check event, not a click event.

Answer (score 28):

Use the [:checked](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checked) selector to determine the checkbox's state:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 14):

For JQuery 1.7+ use:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 8):

This code does what your need:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" >check it</input>

$("#check").change( function(){
   if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        alert("checked");
    }else{
        alert("unchecked");
   }
});
```

Also, you can check it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RredCat/tq0anwwq/)

Answer (score 4):

Use below code snippet to achieve this.:

```
$('#checkAll').click(function(){
  $("#checkboxes input").attr('checked','checked');
});

$('#UncheckAll').click(function(){
  $("#checkboxes input").attr('checked',false);
});
```

Or you can do the same with single check box:

```
$('#checkAll').click(function(e) {
  if($('#checkAll').attr('checked') == 'checked') {
    $("#checkboxes input").attr('checked','checked');
    $('#checkAll').val('off');
  } else {
    $("#checkboxes input").attr('checked', false);
    $('#checkAll').val('on'); 
  }
});
```

For demo: http://jsfiddle.net/creativegala/hTtxe/

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, I've had to leverage the event's currentTarget:

```
$("#dingus").click( function (event) {
   if ($(event.currentTarget).is(':checked')) {
     //checkbox is checked
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use the click event for best compatibility with MSIE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
        alert("state changed");
    });
});
```

Comment: How to judge if it's checked on or not?

Comment: I need to know whether a click mean to check or uncheck it.

Comment: you can then use $(this).is(':checked') to test the state of the just-clicked item

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    checkUncheckAll("#select_all","[name='check_boxes[]']");
});

var NUM_BOXES = 10;
// last checkbox the user clicked
var last = -1;
function check(event) {
  // in IE, the event object is a property of the window object
  // in Mozilla, event object is passed to event handlers as a parameter
  event = event || window.event;

  var num = parseInt(/box\[(\d+)\]/.exec(this.name)[1]);
  if (event.shiftKey && last != -1) {
    var di = num > last ? 1 : -1;
    for (var i = last; i != num; i += di)
      document.forms.boxes['box[' + i + ']'].checked = true;
  }
  last = num;
}
function init() {
  for (var i = 0; i < NUM_BOXES; i++)
    document.forms.boxes['box[' + i + ']'].onclick = check;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body onload="init()">
  <form name="boxes">
    <input name="box[0]" type="checkbox">
    <input name="box[1]" type="checkbox">
    <input name="box[2]" type="checkbox">
    <input name="box[3]" type="checkbox">
    <input name="box[4]" type="checkbox">
    <input name="box[5]" type="checkbox">
    <input name="box[6]" type="checkbox">
    <input name="box[7]" type="checkbox">
    <input name="box[8]" type="checkbox">
    <input name="box[9]" type="checkbox">
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey!buddy,what are you doing here?

Comment: Looks like a range selection (ie, check the first item, hold shift down, check the last one; and all the ones between are checked.)  However, this is much more than the question asks for. Missing some code though, like checkUncheckAll().