# Why isn't my checkbox change event triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, click

I have two functions.

The first function translates a div click into a checked/unchecked toggle.
The second function translates a checkbox change into a hide/show event.

The problem is that when I use the first function to check/uncheck the box, the second function is not called. I am new to javascript, thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":checkbox").parent().click(function(evt) {
        if (evt.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
            var $checkbox = $(":checkbox", this);
            $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
            evt.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":checkbox").change(function() {
        if($(this).attr("checked")) {
            $('.'+this.id).show();
        }
        else {
            $('.'+this.id).hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The **change** event does not fire when you programmatically change the value of a check box.  What you can do to ensure it fires is:

```
 $(":checkbox").parent().click(function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
        var $checkbox = $(":checkbox", this);
        $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
        $checkbox.change();
    }
});
```

Comment: Your theory checks out and your solution works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Better to use (at least with some versions of jQuery)  `$.fn.prop` vs `$.fn.attr`.  Attr will assign as well as retrieve.  Prop just retrieves.

Answer (score 5):

Don't bother with the first snippet. Just use LABEL elements:

```
<label><input type="checkbox">Some option</label>
```

Now, when the user clicks the label (the text next to the checkbox), the checkbox will be activated.

---

The second snippet can be optimized:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    $('#' + this.id).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Comment: the $('.' + this.id) selector wont work. Need to use '#'. And we dont know whats in the div, you are assuming he is using it as a label, it might be something else.

Answer (score 1):

you are using `'.'` which is for class selectors instead use `'#'` since you are using the element ID. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":checkbox").bind('change', function() {
        if($(this).attr("checked")) {
            $('#'+this.id).show();
        }
        else {
            $('#'+this.id).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the OP did that on purpose.. ;) he's not hiding/showing the checkboxes but the `<div>` with a class equivalent to the id of the checkbox.

Comment: @Victor That wouldn't make sense, since the check-box is the element that got that ID.

Comment: @Sime I dont try to make sense of what they are trying to do. If thats the case it was unclear.

Comment: @Reigel Fair enough, but without the markup your guess is just as good as mine. But i guess it makes sense.

Comment: @Victor So when the visitor checks the check-box it should become visible? But it already was visible, otherwise the visitor couldn't have checked it. That does not make sense.

Comment: @Sime I agree it doesnt make sense. I have seen weirder things. I guess we'll just have to wait for the OP to see what he is trying to do.