# Call event when checkbox value is modified but not clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown list containing width values:

- val1
- val2
- val3
- all

And I also have three checkboxes:

- val1
- val2
- val3

The checkboxes are responsible for a progress bar, all of them have an `onclick` function and they are working well. 
I want to make them work when I use the `dropdown` list too but I can't. So when I select a value from the `dropdown` list it modifies the checkboxes `checked` attribute but has no effect on the progress bar and I don't know why.

Comment: Show your effort. Add the code that you have tried.

Comment: You should trigger an event manually, check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript

Comment: "I want to make them work when I use the dropdown list too".. I guess some part of the picture is still inside your head and definitely not here

Comment: Please just a suggestion for the future post. Whenever posting any question on the SO, please do also post the HTML markup and the code that you have tried. That would help us to provide better answers!

Comment: This is a real problem. I have no permission to post the real code.
The question is, how can I manipulate a progress bar with checkboxes which are checked or unchecked with jQuery (through a dropdown list)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery (as you are, according to your tags), set up an event handler for the `change` event. But you must trigger the `change` event manually, since you change the value programatically.

Some information for the manual triggering of the `change` event [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869981/why-isnt-my-checkbox-change-event-triggered)