# jQuery update DOM and have change() method run

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've got a bunch of checkboxes that I want to have trigger a callback when their state is toggled, so I added this (working) line:

```
$('.main').change(mainChecked);
```

And then in the `mainChecked` method I look at the `this` variable and do the appropriate thing whether it was checked or not.  Now, elsewhere in my code I want to check some of those so I just did:

```
$('[data-auto-select]').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

My problem is that while they do get checked, the `mainChecked()` function doesn't get called for them.  How do I check them in such a way that the `mainChecked()` method also automatically gets called?

Comment: That's answered here :)

http://stackoverflow.com/a/4870054/448865

Thanks
Cp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't my checkbox change event triggered?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869981/why-isnt-my-checkbox-change-event-triggered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use script to change the value of an input element the change event will not get triggered, though you can [manually trigger](http://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/) it

```
$('[data-auto-select]').prop('checked', true).change();
//or $('[data-auto-select]').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
```

Also use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) to set the checked state instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr)