# See checkbox value when checked

Tags: html, checkbox

If i have a list of checkboxes and they have the same name and different values.
I want to write the value from the checkboxes i have checked in a new column in real-time.
How can i do this ?

```
<div id="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" name="prod" value="Option 1" checked="checked" />Option 1
<input type="checkbox" name="prod" value="Option 2" />Option 2
<input type="checkbox" name="prod" value="Option 3" />Option 3
<input type="checkbox" name="prod" value="Option 4" checked="checked" />Option 4
</div>
```

Result:

Option 1
Option 4

Comment: Don't forget to validate the answer please.

Comment: do you understand how stackoverflow works ? You post a question, many answers occur and you have to validate one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/). Here a live sample that can inspire you:

```js
$("#checkboxes input").click(function () {
  $("#output").text($("#checkboxes input:checked").map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get().join());
}).click().click();

// or
// var updateOutput = function() {
//  $("#output").text($("#checkboxes input:checked").map(function () {
//    return $(this).val();
//  }).get().join());
//};
//$("#checkboxes input").click(updateOutput);
//updateOutput();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" name="prod" value="Option 1" checked="checked" />Option 1
<input type="checkbox" name="prod" value="Option 2" />Option 2
<input type="checkbox" name="prod" value="Option 3" />Option 3
<input type="checkbox" name="prod" value="Option 4" checked="checked" />Option 4
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

2 JS options :

- double `click`
- use an external function (in comment)

Comment: thanks, this was what i was looking fore. A question thou.
Why is all my checkboxes checked? i have deleted checked="checked" in the input.

Comment: If the answer is good, you can validate it. For your another question, where did you delete checked attributes, in HTML ? with JS ?

Comment: i was delete the checked="checked" in the HTML. So no one is checked. So only the click is sent to output.

Comment: I don't understand. There is no `checked` attributes and all your checkbox are `checked` at loading ?

Comment: yes, if i remove all Checked="checked" from the HTML-checkboxes with value Option 1 and Option 4, all become checked when loaded.

Comment: Ok, you right. It's because I click() once to execute the code once. I'll propose a fix.

Comment: Good, you can validate the answer now!

Answer (score 0):

you can listen for click/change events on your inputs - see this : [Catch checked change event of a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455223/catch-checked-change-event-of-a-checkbox)

And then use jquery's val() function to get the value

Answer (score 0):

var x = new Array();

```
$('input[name="prod"]').each(function(index){

    if($(this).is(':checked')){

        x[index] = $(this).val();

    }

});
```

console.log(x[0]); // gives option 1
 console.log(x[1]); // gives option 4

x is an array that contains the checked value which you may use as per your wish!! :)