# Checkbox state change detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a scenario in which i am showing/Hiding a portion of the screen depending on whether the check box is checked or now.

So the catch here is that, Not only the user will be changing the state of the check box, but also programmatically.

So how do i detect this change and when ever the state of check box is changed , i want to section to be hidden or shown.

Presently i am doing like this...

```
    externalCheckBoxClicked : function (e){
        var $target = $(e.target),
          checked = $target.prop('checked');

        if(checked){
            $('#confirm-button').show();
        }else{
            $('#confirm-button').hide();
        }
    }

    setToPreviousSetValues : function(){
        if(this.requestData.isOverrideExternalParams === "1"){
            $('#ExternalParametersChkBox').prop('checked',true);
        }else {
            $('#ExternalParametersChkBox').prop('checked',false);
        }
    },

   events: {
       "change #ExternalParametersChkBox":"externalCheckBoxClicked",
    },
```

Any Clue why this is not working.

Comment: just add a `change` event listener to the checkbox. which is where by the way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#yourID').change(function() {
  // your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
$(".checkbox").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

You can add `.checkbox` this place Something `Class` File Or `Id` file

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="something" />

$("#something").click( function(){
   if( $(this).is(':checked') ) alert("checked");
});
```

Doing this will not catch when the checkbox changes for other reasons than a click, like using the keyboard. To avoid this problem, listen to changeinstead of click.

Source: [Catch checked change event of a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455223/catch-checked-change-event-of-a-checkbox)

For programmatically changing: [Why isn't my checkbox change event triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869981/why-isnt-my-checkbox-change-event-triggered)