# How to disable other checkboxes on click of one check box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, disabled-control

How can I do this?

- If `Replacement of Registration` is clicked, disable `Honorable Dismissal` and `Entrance Exam`
- If `Good Moral Certificate` is clicked, disable `Entrace Exam`
- If `Honorable Dismissal`, disable `Diploma`, `CUE Request`, `CMI Request`, `Entrance Exam`
- If `Transcript of Record` is clicked, disable `CUE Request`, `CMI Request`, `Entrance Exam`
- If `Entrance Exam`, disable all

---

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ac_description[]" value="Replacement_of_Registration">
<input type="checkbox" name="ac_description[]" value="Good_Moral_Certificate">
<input type="checkbox" name="ac_description[]" value="Honorable_Dismissal " >
<input type="checkbox" name="ac_description[]" value="Transcript_of_Record">
<input type="checkbox" name="ac_description[]" value="Diploma">
<input type="checkbox" name="ac_description[]" value="CUE_Request">
<input type="checkbox" name="ac_description[]" value="CMI_Request">
<input type="checkbox" name="ac_description[]" value="Entrance_Exam">
<input type="checkbox" name="ac_description[]" value="School_fees-Medical/Dental_Laboratory">
<input type="checkbox" name="ac_description[]" value="School_fees-Transcript/Honorable">
<input type="checkbox" name="ac_description[]" value="School_fees-Library">
<input type="checkbox" name="ac_description[]" value="Affiliation_Fees">
```

Comment: Are you trying to disable ALL the other boxes whenever one box has been checked or disable SOME certain boxes?

Comment: So change events and logic

Comment: -if Replacement of Registration is clicked, disable Honorable Dismissal and Entrance Exam
-if Good Moral Certificate is clicked, disable Entrace Exam
-if Honorable Dismissal, disable Diploma, CUE Request, CMI Request, Entrance Exam
-if Transcript of Record is clicked, disable CUE Request, CMI Request, Entrance Exam
-if Entrance Exam, disable all

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems do you have with that code?

Comment: at least provide some script on what you had done and what is the problem you facing on the script that you create, by just requesting answer won't help you much

Answer (score 0):

You will put disabled at the end of the input tag for example:

```
<input type = "checkbox"name = "ac_description[]" value = "Good_Moral_Certificate" >
<input type = "checkbox" name = "ac_description[]" value = "Honorable_Dismissal " >
<input type = "checkbox" name = "ac_description[]" value = "Transcript_of_Record">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "ac_description[]" value = "Diploma" disabled>
```

The fourth checkbox will be disabled. You can manipulate it using jQuery.
Using jQuery you could have an event happen when a checkbox is triggered it applies the disabled attribute to the other boxes.
Take a look at this answer: [Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery)

If you want to disable a group, assign a class to each group of inputs then use jQuery to change them. Take a look at this post as well: [Catch checked change event of a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455223/catch-checked-change-event-of-a-checkbox)

Here is an example of what you might want to try:

```
$('.class_name').each( function(){
$this.onClick( function(){
if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
    $('.class_name').each( function(){
    if( $(this).not(':checked') ){
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    }
  })
}
```

})
});

Comment: You might want to make a class for each grouping that you can only select one checkbox from. Then for each class assign a listener.

Answer (score 0):

Pieced this code snippet from whats understood from your question,

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
  var val = $(this).attr('value');
  switch(val) {
    case 'Replacement_of_Registration':
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
      $("input[value='Honorable_Dismissal '], input[value='Entrance_Exam']").prop('disabled',true);
    else
      $("input[value='Honorable_Dismissal '], input[value='Entrance_Exam']").prop('disabled',false);
  break;
  case 'Good_Moral_Certificate':
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
      $("input[value='Entrance_Exam']").prop('disabled',true);
    else
      $("input[value='Entrance_Exam']").prop('disabled',false);
  break;
  case 'Honorable_Dismissal ':
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
      $("input[value='Diploma'], input[value='CUE_Request'], input[value='CMI_Request'], input[value='Entrance_Exam']").prop('disabled',true);
    else
      $("input[value='Diploma'], input[value='CUE_Request'], input[value='CMI_Request'], input[value='Entrance_Exam']").prop('disabled',false);
  break;
  case 'Transcript_of_Record':
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
      $("input[value='CUE_Request'], input[value='CMI_Request'], input[value='Entrance_Exam']").prop('disabled',true);
    else
      $("input[value='CUE_Request'], input[value='CMI_Request'], input[value='Entrance_Exam']").prop('disabled',false);
  break;
  case 'Entrance_Exam':
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
      $("input[name='ac_description[]']").not(this).prop('disabled',true);
    else
      $("input[name='ac_description[]']").not(this).prop('disabled',false);
  break;
});
```

Comment: still It is not functioning.